# doing while loop and for loop over matrix with conditions to terminate the loop python

Tags: python

Halo,i am new to programming and python. Last time i have posted a question concerning loops i have understood the concept and developed several algorithms. Now, i was trying to apply the concept over matrix and lists. Here is the code i was trying to iterate through:

```
import numpy as np
R=np.matrix([[1,2,1,3,4,2],[2,1,2,1,2,3],[1,1,2,3,1,2],[1,2,3,1,1,1],[2,1,2,4,1,2],
[1,3,1,1,2,3]])# this 6 by 6 matrix

loads=np.transpose(np.matrix([0,0,0,0,0,0])) # this is starting load
tk=[2,2,2,2]
stress=[]
kk=True
while (kk):
for i in range(len(tk)):
    loads+=np.transpose(np.matrix([1,0,0,0,0,0]))
    mid=R*loads
    stress_k=mid[0:3]+tk[i]*mid[3:6]
    stress.append(stress_k)
    stressk=(np.bmat(stress))
    s=stressk[0:1,i:i+1]
    if s>20:
        kk=False
        break

print(stressk)
print(loads)
print(i)
print(s)
```

the problem is that when i try to print the terminating load print(s) the loop goes until the range length which is 4, and repeats the cycle over and over.The repeating vector is[[12]]infinitely. more over the print(loads) increase infinitely in with out affecting the
 stress_k value.My intention was to stop the loop when the loads have reached certain value that it would make the element of stressk matrix[i,j] greater 20, which in this case i have selected the first row and to loop through the column [0:1,i:i+1]. i have tried many other method but can not find the mistake. i kindly request if some one can fix the code or tell me if any other method exist.Thanks in advance jack

Comment: Is the while necessary?

Comment: Don't use break. Use loop with multiple conditions instead.

Comment: i guess yes because the loop will terminate at the end of the range(len(tk)) and stop looping. but if i use while it will continue until the condition( s>20) and break out of the loop. user189

Comment: If that is the case (that you want to run until s>20), then check your indentation. As is, the if clause runs within the for loop. You want it to run outside of the for loop within the while loop.

Comment: how would i avoid the break? by using the elif and else? almanegra

Comment: Your code should work though. I think 's' is never higher than 20. That's why the loop is running till the end